# Make a HTML Table row "inactive"

Tags: html

I have a HTML table with different products, their description, the quantity that is in stock and a button to decrease the quantity.

When the quantity is zero, I would like to make the row with this product grayed out or inactive and put it at the end of the table.

Is there an easy way to do this with HTML or Bootstrap?

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: No, there is no way to make it via HTML. You need Js/jQuery/etc. to re-sort your table and change class on that row.